# Crystal reports for Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I've just installed Support Pack 15 from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 . I've been told after install it will be working with my VS 2015 on Windows 10. After installation i realased when choosing new item to project crystal report appear on list, but within Toolbox i can't see any crystal report control especially rystal report viewer. Any idea what has to be done to fix it?

**UPDATE:** Think i was able to solve that by changing Framework 4 client profile to net framework 4 in project properties, after that change controls appears.

NEW QUESTION: When i will publish my app and considering this change - when my client download new published version will not be a problem for him when executing app?

Comment: Whoever has downvoted your question thinks of himself as over-smart. The system clearly says "Consider adding a comment" which they havent.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. In my case I even not see Crystal Report in new item list.

Answer (score 2):

If you are publishing your application using ClickOnce you can download the redistributable files from this page and include them: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

If you can test first with a test machine before rolling out it would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone else was having a similar issue with Crystal Reports, regarding the first part of your question.  The solution I gave for that person can be found here: 
[How to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531668/integrate-sap-crystal-report-in-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-edition)

Regarding your second question, I'm not 100% sure, but I wouldn't expect your friend to have a problem if you're able to successfully compile and run the app.

Hope this helps.