# How to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded VS 2015. I want to integrate SAP Crystal Reports in VS 2015 Enterprise Edition. I have also downloaded the MSI file of the latest SAP Crystal Report edition and installed it. However, I am not able to see the Crystal Report Viewer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a very difficult time finding this particular download page and the appropriate download link on that page for Visual Studio 2015 (I also have Enterprise but I don't think that matters too much, if at all for this).  The link is provided below, the download link is titled, "Support Pack 15 (v.13.0.15.1840)".
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

So I did the following:

```
1.) I had to uninstall two Crystal Report applications that I had previously installed (one was an update for it I think).

2.) Then I shutdown VS2015.

3.) Then I ran the downloaded executable, it installed fine and I installed the 64 bit run-time feature for Crystal Reports.

4.) Then I made a mistake and tried opening VS2015 afterwards, it crashed repeatedly. 

5.)  After restarting the PC, I have no more errors and I now have the crystal reports icon in the Report's category when adding a new
item to my Web Application project. It also allows me to use the wizard.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the same process like you but still I am unable to find crystal report menu

Comment: Okay, I suggest removing/uninstalling any software related to Crystal Reports and then reinstall the "Support Pack."  Restart the PC, open Visual Studio and I'll hope that you see it there.  -- I had to uninstall all software related to crystal reports before I got this to work.  I hope this suggestion helps.

Comment: Finally got the crystal report option with visual studio 2015 with update 1

Comment: Nice job!  I should have included that information in my original answer to you because I'm using VS2015 with Update 1.  I'm glad you now have the Crystal Reports option now.

Comment: Apparently uninstalling and installing it back again is the key. Happened twice, resolved twice with the same approach. Not very convincing though

Answer (score 15):

You can download it from:

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

- Download "Crystal Reports", click in the link "Support Pack 16" ((#1 in the picture)) for developers.
- Download the "Run time", clic in the link "MSI 32/64 Bit" ((#2 in the picture)) for the clients.

[image: Crystal Reports]

---

Finally, restart your PC.... open your visual studio 2015 again and you will see "Reporting" option for Crystal Reports when you add a new item.

Happy code!

[image]

Comment: That's fine and dandy, your instructions worked, but I don't want to create a new Crystal Report. I want to look at one that already exists without changing it. We are trying to move our reports from Crystal to SSRS.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from this link http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_18.exe

After installing, Open Visual Studio,

- Create a folder for the reports
- Right Click and Add new Item
- Go to Reporting

You will see Crystal Report on the list. Select that and start designing.