# crystal report viewer doesn't appear in toolbox visual studio 2015

Tags: c#

crystal report viewer doesn't appear in toolbox visual studio 2015

I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: you try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531668/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-edition

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.